# Moveit can't execute a plan with MoveGroupInterface

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to move a group from my own robot with a joint goal, with the MoveGroupInterface class.
When I use move() the group moves perfectly to the joint goal in rviz.

Now I want to add constraints and time parameterization, so I generated a plan with the planning pipeline :

planning_pipeline->generatePlan(planning_scene, req, res);

The trajectory created is correct, but when I try to execute it in Rviz the robot doesn't move, even though I get a "SUCCEED" message for the execution.

How can I execute and visualize a trajectory created with the planning pipeline ? I tried several methods from the moveit tutorials, and never got a result.
Thanks

I use :

Ubuntu 18.04
ROS melodic (from binaries)
Moveit (from binaries)

I use the demo.launch file.

My code :

planning_pipeline->generatePlan(planning_scene, req, res);
robot_trajectory::RobotTrajectory trajectory = *res.trajectory_;
vector  joint_names = {"J1_right", "J2_right", "J3_right", "J4_right"};

```
moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory_msg;
trajectory.getRobotTrajectoryMsg(trajectory_msg);

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group(group);    
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;
plan.trajectory_ = trajectory_msg;
plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.header.frame_id = trajectory_msg.joint_trajectory.header.frame_id;
plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.joint_names = joint_names;

cout<<"EXECUTE PLAN"<<endl;
move_group.plan(plan);       // I tried with .plan(), without .plan(), and with .move()
move_group.execute(plan);
```

Console output :

> [ INFO] [1587753968.681163408]:
> Looking around: no [ INFO]
> [1587753968.681232961]: Replanning: no
> [ INFO] [1587754003.859250207]:
> Execution request received [ INFO]
> [1587754003.930022457]: Fake execution
> of trajectory [ INFO]
> [1587754004.229404023]: Completed
> trajectory execution with status
> SUCCEEDED ... [ INFO]
> [1587754004.229801013]: Execution
> completed: SUCCEEDED

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350513/moveit-can%27t-execute-a-plan-with-movegroupinterface/) by [edote](https://answers.ros.org/users/52093/edote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't remember why, but the variable time_from_start in  plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points[] was empty, so my robot jumped from start state to goal state but the trajectory didn't have the time to execute.
Now I use res.getMessage(response) (https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/motion_planning_pipeline/motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial.html#visualize-the-result), and it works.

---

Originally posted by [edote](https://answers.ros.org/users/52093/edote/) with karma: 36 on 2020-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0